# Accessing attribute from devexpress PopUpMenu

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I would like to know how to receive RowId from popupmenu and name from menuitem on which i clicked.

This is my code:

```
<script>
function OnWorkflowChanged(popup)
{
    alert(menuitem.name + popup.RowId);}
 </script>

<def:PopupMenu ID="popup" ClientInstanceName="popup" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" PopupElementID="imgState" RowId='<%# Eval("ItemNodeId") %>' PopupAction="RightMouseClick">
<ClientSideEvents ItemClick='function(s, e) {  OnWorkflowChanged(s) }' />
<Items>
    <def:menuitem name="type1" text="<%$ Resources: type1%>" Image-Url="~/images/checkbox0.png" />
    <def:menuitem name="type2" text="<%$ Resources: type2%>" Image-Url="~/images/checkbox1.png" />
    <def:menuitem name="type3" text="<%$ Resources: type3%>" Image-Url="~/images/checkbox2.png"/>
    <def:menuitem name="type4" text="<%$ Resources: type4%>" Image-Url="~/images/s_all.png" ItemStyle-BorderTop-BorderStyle="Solid" ItemStyle-BorderTop-BorderWidth="1px" ItemStyle-BorderTop-BorderColor="LightGray" />
    <def:menuitem name="type5" text="<%$ Resources: type5%>" Image-Url="~/images/z_all.png" />
```

Thank you.

Edit: So I figured out how to pass menuitem. It's really easy - e.item.name. But I still have no idea how to pass RowId.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [custom JS properties](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxMenuASPxMenuBase_JSPropertiestopic). Set it to the required value on the server and obtain on the client. Here a code snippet: [How to: Access Server Data on the Client Side](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11816).